# The fastest way to count the number of files in a directory (including subdirectories)

Tags: linux, performance

I'm running a script that looks at all the files in a directory and its subdirectories.

The script has been running for a day, and I'd like to estimate how long it will keep running. I know how many files it processed so far (73,000,000), but I don't know the total number of files.

What is the fastest way to count the files?

I tried right-clicking on the directory and selecting "properties", and it's slowly counting up.
I tried redirecting ls into a file, and it's just churning & churning...

Should I write a program in c?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fast Linux File Count for a large number of files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1427032/fast-linux-file-count-for-a-large-number-of-files)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I did a quick research. Using a directory with 100,000 files I compared the following commands:

```
ls -R <dir>
ls -lR <dir>
find <dir> -type f
```

I ran them twice, once redirecting into a file (`>file`), and once piping into wc (`|wc -l`). Here are the run times in seconds:

```
        >file   |wc
ls -R     14     14
find      89     56
ls -lR    91     82
```

The difference between `>file` and `|wc -l` is smaller than the difference between `ls` and `find`.

It appears that `ls -R` is at least **4x** faster than `find`.

Comment: I can't undo my upvote, but this is wrong. `ls -R` may be faster, but it also gives incorrect results. First off, this counts directories as well as files. Worse yet, the output is formatted, and those formatting lines are counted as well.

Answer (score 7):

The simplest way:

```
find <dir> -type f | wc -l
```

Slightly faster, perhaps:

```
find <dir> -type f -printf '\n' | wc -l
```

Comment: do you think find will be faster than ls?

Comment: It'll be faster than saving `ls`'s output to a file. It'll be on par with `ls -R | wc -l`.

Answer (score 2):

Fastest I know about:

```
ls | wc -l
```

Note: keep in mind though that it lists *all* nodes inside a directory, including subdirectories and the two references to the current and the parent directory (`.` & `..`).

If you need the *recursive count* of files in all subdirectories (as opposed to everything including subdirectories inside the current directory), then you can add the "recursive" flag to the `ls` command:

```
ls -R | wc -l
```

If you compare this in speed to the suggestion using `find` you will see that it is much faster (factor 2 to 10), but keep in mind the note above.

Comment: This misses the files in subdirectories.

Comment: @RSamuelKlatchko Yeah, just added that option as a seconf alternative. The OPs question is a bit vague about this...

Comment: I tried ls -R, and I'm redirecting it into a file instead of piping into wc, so that I can see how far it got. It's still running. So I was wondering if there's a fastest way.

Comment: Hm, `ls` is _pretty_ fast. Could it be that your performance issue is writing to the file? Keep in mind that writing files is a very slow process...

Comment: Sure, I see the problem, but slowing it down further certainly won't help :-) I doubt you can find or implement something really faster than the `ls` command.

Comment: `ls` can even be faster than `ls`  if you add the `-f` switch. Something faster than the `ls` command? No problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28368788/276232

Comment: `ls -R` has formatting in the output that makes the resulting count incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

`ls` is **not** fast at all, and for your purpose is not even valuable: indeed `ls` prints an alhabetically sorted list of items, so have to wait for the OS to return the whole list of entries, sort them, print in the standard output, an then filter the result looking for newline characters.

A looooot of work for a simple task and even worse: if some of your file has a newline in the name, you'll count it more than once.

`find`, on the other hand, dosn't sort. It also have the advantage of immediatly executing the actions when the buffer is returned from the File System, so you'll start seeing result immediatly, and will consume far less memory.

So prefer this approach instead:

```bash
find . -mindepth 0 -maxdepth 0 -ignore_readdir_race -prinf x | wc -m
```

It will print an "x" in the standard output for every item found in the current directory (excluded the current directory itself, with `-mindepth 1`), and don't recurse (`-maxdepth 1`), then count the chracters.

Given that the folder is **very** full, `-ignore_readdir_race` will ignore errors for files deleted while counting

If you want to know the current count, redirect the output to a file (possibly in a tmpfs, so all is in-memory, and you won't produce a bottleneck), then detach the process. When you want to know the current counter's value, simply `wc -m /tmp/count.txt`:

```bash
nohup find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -ignore_readdir_race -printf x > /tmp/count.txt &
```

Then when you want to see the actual count:

```bash
wc -m /tmp/count.txt
```

Or just keep watching it increase...

```bash
watch wc -m /tmp/count.txt
```

Have fun